# Getting value from json/javascript array of name/value pairs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array of name/value pairs and I'm looking at a sensible way to be able to adjust the value for a particular name in the array. e.g.

```
var myArr = [{"name":"start","value":1},{"name":"end","value":15},{"name":"counter","value":"6"},{"name":"user","value":"Bert"}]
```

I can use

```
$.each(myArr, function (key, pair) {
if (pair.name == 'user')
{
  pair.value = 'bob';
}
});
```

but in reality my object has tens of values and I would like to be able to change them much more simply than adding an `if` for each one.

Ideally `myArr['user'].value = 'bob';` or something similar.

Comment: If you are doing server-side programming then you can convert it to JSON / GSON type Array and  then iterate through it to get KVP.

Comment: @BlueChippy If possible, then I recommend you change your json structure to something like this: `{"start":1",end":15,"counter":6,"user":"Bert"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects in an array.  An array does not have any indexing method that gives you direct lookup like you asked for;

```
myArr['user'].value = 'bob';
```

To get that, you would need to restructure your data so that you had an object where the name was the main key and inside that key was another object with the rest of your data for that user like this:

```
var myData = {
    "start": {value: 1},
    "end": {value: 15},
    "user": {value: Bert}
};
```

The, you could directly access by name as in:

```
myData['user'].value = 'bob;
```

---

If you wanted to stick with your existing data structure, then the simplest thing I can think of is to make a simple function that finds the right object:

```
function findUser(data, nameToFind) {
   var item;
   for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
       item = nameToFind[i];
       if (item.name === nameToFind) {
           return item;
       }
   }
}

var myArr = [{"name":"start","value":1},{"name":"end","value":15},{"name":"counter","value":"6"},{"name":"user","value":"Bert"}]
```

Then, you could do something like this:

```
findUser(myArr, "user").value = "bob";
```

This assumes you're only looking for data that is in the array because otherwise, this will create an error unless you add error checking to it.

---

If you just really want to turn the whole thing into a function that finds and changes the name, it can be like this:

```
function changeUser(data, nameToFind, newName) {
   var item;
   for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
       item = nameToFind[i];
       if (item.name === nameToFind) {
           item.name = newName;
           return;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sadly can't restructure as not my data :(

Comment: @BlueChippy - they you can't do what you're asking for because an array isn't indexed by key like an object is - it's just a flat list of entries.  I've added another alternative to my answer without data restructuring.

Comment: Exactly... It would be easier to work with a json like this `{"start":1",end":15,"counter":6,"user":"Bert"}`

Answer (score 0):

Add this function:

```
function SetArrayValue(arr, key, value, stopOnFirstMatch) {
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].name === key) {
       arr[i].value = value
       if (stopOnFirstMatch !== undefined && stopOnFirstMatch) return
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
SetArrayValue(myArr, 'user', 'bob')
```

Comment: More promising - but is there a way to stop iterating if found - so if I set the second value it stops after iterating the second value?

Comment: Are you sure you want to apply first match only? It's possible you have multiple values for one key

Comment: Good point, however I know in this particular case the "name" will be unique for each value.

Comment: I'll add additional param to function

Answer (score 0):

I will award the points for the best answer, but I actually solved it a completely different way:

First build up a list of "names" in the order they appear:

```
var keys = [];
 $.each(myArr, function (key, pair) {
 keys.push(pair.name);
 });
```

then I can use:

```
myArr[keys.indexOf('sEcho')].value = 'whatever';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This 
$.grep(myArr,function(e){return e.name=="user"})[0].value="ppp"

You can use the $.greb() of jquery.